# Manage resource that can't be shared

Tags: database, algorithm, architecture, resources, locking

Today, we have a resource that can't be shared. We have a table to manage this resource, it works like a queue and it's ordered by the last usage date of the resource. As a consumer requests for this resource, we "lock" the registry in the database, and when a consumer is done using it, we unlock this same registry and update it's last usage date. The problem with this solution is that we need "lock" the registries too many times, and it's not guaranteed that only one consumer is using the resource. 
So, we would like to know, is there any better way to achieve this result using another strategy?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, there's also Database Administrators: https://dba.stackexchange.com/